# Is it possible to have a dependent clause without a verb?

Tags: dependent-clause

**What with the high prices since the war started,** we'll be made up if it lasts.

This sentence has been taken from an app of Oxford Dictionary. I had made a search to find the use of *make*. Then I got the sentence stated above. Please, discuss the construction of *what with the high prices since the war started*. I think **What with high prices** is a dependent clause. But I don't find any verb in it.

I want to say more about my question. Actually, I want to know if there are any kind of dependent clauses that do not have any verb. If there are, please state the rules about how to form a dependent clause without a verb. Also, I want to know whether or not *what with the high prices* is a dependent clause without a verb.

The sentence stated above is just an example. Please discuss about the answer to my question as well as the sentence stated above in your own way.

Comment: 'What with the high prices since the war started, we'll be made up if it lasts.' Compare 'Because of / As a result of the high prices since the war started, we'll be made up if it lasts.' Before the comma, these use prepositional phrases, with the compound prepositions because of / as a result of / what with.  [Cinková et al](https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/techrep/tr35.pdf) has  '... the line between collocations with prepositional function and complex prepositions is especially fine in the three-word combinations'

Answer (score 1):

The implied verb is 'be'.  The implied subject is 'time'.  The pronoun 'what' is superfluous.